# How to increase text inside div with its size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added multiple dynamic divs inside a container div. Each div contains text. Its works fine. But when I added resizable functionality to a div using jquery library. I am able to resize div's but its text size is static. What I want when i increase the div size its text size should also increase and vice versa.

Below is the code with which I have adding resizable functionality and appending to a parent.

```
          var div = document.createElement('div');
           $(div).attr("id", "dyndiv" + count); 
           objid = "dyndiv" + count ;
           count++;
      var $ctrl = $(div).text($('#txttext').val()).addClass("draggable ui-widget-content").draggable({ containment: '#containment-wrapper', cursor: 'move', snap: '#containment-wrapper' }).resizable({ aspectRatio:true, containment: '#containment-wrapper' }); 

            $("#containment-wrapper").append($ctrl);
```

Comment: you will need to modify the css and change the font-size basically. You can do this on the callback function in resizable. As to how much you want to resize it by, i don't know. You'll need to figure that part out. Maybe calculate the area and increase size by a percentage?

Comment: in this objid is the div id which user had selected               $( $('#' + objid) ).resizable({
   resize: function(event, ui) {  
  .....   }    but this is not executing
please can you validate it ...or give me an example to add call back function   
});

Comment: sure, i added it down below as an answer with a jsfiddle script.

Comment: Thanks matt. I want little bit more calrification regarding (".selector"). this should i replace with my id.

Comment: yes, sort of. In your code where it says resizeable, you will need to add the resize callback function. I made an edit to my answer with part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example of what i mean, you may need to mess with the calculation though to include height some how as of right now you can have a small height, but a large text that doesnt exactly fit in the box.

http://jsfiddle.net/HpSwu/1/

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
       newSize = $(this).width()*0.1;
       $(this).css('font-size', newSize );
    }
});
```

---

## EDIT

Something like:

```
var $ctrl = $(div).text($('#txttext').val())
            .addClass("draggable ui-widget-content")
            .draggable({ 
                 containment: '#containment-wrapper', 
                 cursor: 'move', 
                 snap: '#containment-wrapper' })
            .resizable({ 
                  aspectRatio:true, 
                  containment: '#containment-wrapper',
                  resize: function(event, ui) {
                     newSize = $(this).width()*0.1;
                     $(this).css('font-size', newSize );
                  }
            });
```

Comment: I have added this functionality but it is not working properly can anybody refined it I have added this on callback function        start: function(event, ui) {
                            ini_text_size_width = $(this).width();
                                },
                                   resize: function (event,ui){
    fin_text_size_width = ($(this).width() / ini_text_size_width);
    $(this).css("font-size" ,( parseInt($(this).css("font-size")) + (fin_text_size_width )) + "pt")
    }  
    });

Comment: @ManojG could you make a new question for that. I can't really tell whats wrong with it, in that format.